# WPF FrameworkElement Mouse Click issue

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, custom-controls, frameworkelement

In a WPF app I have I bunch of CustomControls inside a Grid. For processing Mouse clicks on them I use the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event of the Grid and in the event handler I check which CustomControl was clicked:

```
private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement feSourceComm = e.Source as FrameworkElement;
        MyCustomControl SCurrentComm = new MyCustomControl();            
        try
        {
            SCurrentComm = (MyCustomControl)feSourceComm;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
...
```

The problem appeared when I placed all CustomControls in a UserControl and then inside the Grid. In this case approach doesn't work. 
I checked the type of click source in each case by `e.Source.GetType().ToString();` and get the following results:

When there are no problem (in case I put CustomControls in the Grid without UserControl)

```
MyProjectNamespace.MyCustomControl
```

When I put CustomControls in the UserControl and then in the Grid

```
MyProjectNamespace.UserControls.MyUserControlName
```

When I put CustomControls in the UserControl and then in the Grid and load the UserControl from external file by `XamlReader.Load`

```
System.Windows.Controls.UserControl
```

So, my question:
**How to make CustomControls vizible as `e.Source` when they are inside of a UserControl?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.OriginalSource` will tell you which specific element the click happened on.  if that is not your customcontrol, walk up the Parent chain of the `OriginalSource` until you find your customcontrol